# Length of element is zero even if it's filled

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to set data attributes with angularjs/js.

```
<article id="desktop">
    <h3>Dein Desktop: </h3>
    <ul>
        <li class="deskElem" data-ng-repeat="x in storage | orderBy: '-name' " >
            {{x.name}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</article>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $http, $window, $timeout){

    //All Objects on Desktop
    $scope.storage = [];     

    //Show Desktop

    $http.get("/getDesktop").then(function(response){
        for(var i = 0; i<response.data.length; i++){
            $scope.storage[i] = {name: response.data[i]};
        }

        $scope.setLetter();
        return;
    });

    $scope.setLetter = function(){
        var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("deskElem");
        console.log(elem);

        for(var j=0; j< elem.length; j++){
            elem[j].setAttribute('data-letters', 
            $scope.storage[j].name.charAt(0));
        }
    }
});
```

And the Java Controller:

```
 //Returns Desktop
@GetMapping("/getDesktop")
public ArrayList<String> getDesktop() throws Exception {
    ArrayList<String> itemNames = new ArrayList<>();

    if(kdxF.getUser() != null) {
        itemNames = kdxF.showDesktop();        // Just returns an 
    ArrayList of strings
    }else {
        throw new Exception("Not logged in!");
    }

    return itemNames;
}
```

The length of the element is zero even if my console.log(elem) displays the elements. Mabe it's cause of the get method but that's just a guess.

Comment: How do you know for sure that `elem.length` and `$scope.storage.length` are the same?  If the list of elements is shorter, then the loop will run off the end and hit `undefined` values.

Comment: `for(var j=0; j<elem.length; j++){`

Comment: I have an ng repeat in my html, thats exactly the length of my storage. And every element of them has the same class "deskElem"

Comment: But well @fcalderan that did the thing. But why?

Comment: try to console.log `elem.length` and `$scope.storage.length`- they must be different.

Comment: @fcalderan Okay, elem.length is 0 here. But that makes no damn sense to me?! If I output elem, it's an html collection with length 4.

Comment: unfortunately this other question can't be easily guessed by the given code

Comment: Okay, I'll add some more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never use DOM search code in controllers. The reason it errors is likely that  digest cycle is needed to first create those elements

You can set this attribute right in the view using `{{x.name[0]}}`

```
<li class="deskElem" data-letters="{{x.name[0]}}" data-ng-repeat="x in storage | orderBy: '-name' ">
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. That did the thing - kinda. :)
Could you explain why I shouldnt use DOM search code in controller?

Comment: Because controllers should never know anything about the elements in the DOM. They are only responsible for scope that the dom uses. Also when you assign new scope variables you have to account for time for angular to rebuild the dom

Answer (score 0):

> You are not doing the angular way .

The models should be tightly bind to the html dome nodes in the view .
When you update models or views , the other will gets updated viceversa .
Read about Angular 2way binding 
Also in your case , Have you defined **ng-app** ?
The boilerplate code will looks like this

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<article id="desktop">
    <h3>Dein Desktop: </h3>
    <ul>
        <li class="deskElem" data-ng-repeat="x in storage | orderBy: '-name' ">
            {{x.name}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</article>
```

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $http.get("/getDesktop").then(function(response) {
        for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
            $scope.storage[i] = {
                name: response.data[i]
            };
        }

        $scope.setLetter();
        return;
    });
});
```

Comment: Of course I set controller/app in html. Set them in the body tag. But I rly dont get what ur saying.

Comment: You don't have to write Lower level Code like document.getElementsByClassName("deskElem")  in angular Environment . Bind your html dome element to a model and just update the model.

Comment: Yep, just like charlietfl said. I didn't know that's possible, but I'm still learning, so I'm grateful for your tips. thanks. :)